# How to get event's data from firebase in python?

Tags: python, firebase, api, google-bigquery

I've got some events which are defined in `Firebase Analytics` section, like the picture below:

[image: firebase events]

The problem is I don't know how to export the data of these events from Firebase via API or using python package.

I have also found `google-cloud-bigquery` package which in case I requested for the datasets and tables it returns null.

Here is the code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from decouple import Config

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = Config("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")
client = bigquery.Client()
print(client.project)

datasets = list(client.list_datasets())
print(datasets) # it prints []
```

More clearly, what I have to do is to execute a query on the database, but I didn't find any link helpful.

```
table_name = 'events_' + two_days_ago
query = """
    SELECT * 
    FROM {}
""".format(table_name)

print(client.query(query).result())
```

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Table name "events_20210507" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.

Is there any way to access the dataset and tables.
I have also followed [this tutorial] but still no datasets and problems are existed!

How can I get rid of these kind of error message? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Linking Firebase to BigQuery**

In order to execute queries (using BigQuery) from Firebase, it is necessary to link them.

Linking process is done after following these steps:

1. Go to [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project) and select your existing project.
2. Select `project settings` from dashboard.

[image: firebase dashboard]

3. Select `Integration` tab and make sure BigQuery is enabled.

[image: BigQuery API]

4. For more details and configuring BigQuery API settings you can click `manage` as it is displayed in the above picture.

**Fixing the problem**

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Table name "events_20210507" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.

This error is because of wrong query. As it is mentioned the problematic query was as below:

```
query = """
    SELECT * 
    FROM {}
""".format(table_name)
```

It must be changed to the following format:

```
query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM {0}.{1}.{2}
    WHERE event_name="{3}";
""".format(project_name, dataset_id, table_name, event_name)
```

**P.S 1**: For more detail you can follow [this link](https://medium.com/@rajajawahar77/exporting-firebaseanalytics-data-using-python-9e0cf58349b8).

**P.S 2** If you faced to access problem, you can get the JSON credentials from [iam service](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts).